# PowerShell Regex Bulk Replace Filenames

Tags: regex, powershell, rename, bulk

I am trying to replace filenames in a given folder, but using regular expressions as a filter and in the new filenames, in PowerShell.

For example, a file name "CEX-13" should be renamed to "C-0013"; "CEX-14" should change to "C-0014", etc.

I have this, but I get an error that I cannot create a file that already exists.

My current code is:

```
foreach ($file in get-childitem | where-object {$_.name -match "^CEX-(\d\d)"})
{
    rename-item $file -newname ($file.name -replace "^CEX-(\d\d)", "C-00$1")
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Debugging tip: `rename-item $file -newname ($file.name -replace "^CEX-(\d\d)", "C-00$1")` -> `$file.name -replace "^CEX-(\d\d)", "C-00$1" | Out-Host`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the dollar in the replacement to get past the PowerShell variable expansion in strings, and stay as a dollar sign as it gets to the regex engine.

Currently `"C-00$1"` becomes `"C-00"` and all the files will get the same name.

You need to escape it with a backtick

```
"C-00`$1"
```

or use single quotes `'C-00$1'`

Comment: Thank you so very much for the quick reply. Worked like a charm